# This при работе c событиями в ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Здравствуйте решил написать простенький класс таймера используя ES6 синктаксис.

Есть две проблемы:
1.Как вынести переменные `tick, min,seconds,minutes` в конструктор, так что б они были видны внутри метода `run()`.
2.При клике на кнопку стоп,таймер должен останавливаться и в `cleatinterval` должна попадать ссылка на таймер из конструтора.

Используя ES5 можно вынести контекст в отдельную функцию и с ней работать, как сделать тоже самое используя новый синтаксис?

```js
class Timer {
 constructor(){
  this.timer;
 }
  
 run(){
  let tick = 0;
  let min = 0
  let seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
  let minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
  this.timer = setInterval( () => {   
   tick++;   
   if(tick == 60){
      min++;
      tick =  0;
      if(min < 9){
    min = '0'+min;
      }
      minutes.innerHTML = min;
   }
   if( tick < 9){
    tick = '0'+tick;
   } 
  
   seconds.innerHTML = tick; 
     
   console.log('timer play');
  },1000)
 }

 stop(){
  console.log(this);//Ссылаетcя на btn
  clearInterval(this.timer);//не работает 
  console.log('timer stop');
 }

}

let main_timer = new Timer;

btn.addEventListener('click',main_timer.run);
stop.addEventListener('click',main_timer.stop);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor(){
    this.timer;
    this.tick;
    this.min;
    this.seconds;
    this.minutes;
}

run(){
    this.tick = 0;
    this.min = 0;

    this.seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
    this.minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
    this.seconds.innerHTML = '';
    this.minutes.innerHTML = '';

    this.timer = setInterval( () => {   
        this.tick++;   
        if(this.tick == 60){
           this.min++;
           this.tick =  0;
           this.minutes.innerHTML = (this.min < 10)? '0' + this.min : this.min;
        }
        this.seconds.innerHTML = (this.tick < 10)? '0' + this.tick : this.tick; 

        console.log('timer play');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Что до контекста, в котором будут выполняться `run` и `stop`:

```
btn.addEventListener('click',main_timer.run.bind(main_timer));
stop.addEventListener('click',main_timer.stop.bind(main_timer));
```

или

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => main_timer.run());
stop.addEventListener('click', () => main_timer.stop());
```

или

```
class Timer {
  ...

  runHandler() { return this.run.bind(this); }
  stopHandler() { return this.stop.bind(this); }

btn.addEventListener('click', main_timer.runHandler());
stop.addEventListener('click', main_timer.stopHandler());
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать тоже самое но только без использования bind,передачи контекста в событие? Что можно было просто использовать main_timer.stop(). Подобно плагину в jQuery?

Comment: "Подобно плагину в jQuery?" - не понял вот это место.

Comment: Что б можно било просто использовать без привязки контекста. например "stop.addEventListener('click',main_timer.stop);

Comment: @JavAs Без привязки кoнтекста у Вас не будет правильного контекста. Смотрите добавление в ответе.

Comment: Все увидел с обновлением, я имел ввиду можно ли указивать контекст внутри класса, и насколько правильно так делать? В любом случаи спасибо!)